# Non-continuous chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I want to show a chart which should be drawn as non-continuous. The chart example is given below;

[image: Chart]

How can it be drawn?

Comment: I think that **[hlines](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hlines#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines)** is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`scatter()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) function in pyplot.